# 2021 M1 MacPro kept crashing (kernel panic)

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

I have a MacPro that's been freezing & restarting randomly every day for since late 2022 and I cannot figure out the cause. I've sent it to Apple Repair but they claimed they didn't find any hardware issue with it and just re-installed Monterey for me, which worked for around two months before the issue reappeared. Since then, I've tried the following approaches but none of them worked.

- upgrade to Sonoma
- disable the FileVault, Bluetooth & remove all the external devices (mouse, HDMI, docking station...)

Can anyone help me with this issue please? I've attached the panic log below, which remains unchanged for each crash.

Thanks!

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe002e6921a0): "AMCC2 PLANE1 MCC_TP_PAR error: INTSTS0 0x00000001 TAG_PAR_ERR_LOG0/1/2=0x30001/0x400e09/0x513ecf00" @AppleT6000PlatformErrorHandler.cpp:2779
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x1
OS release type: User
OS version: 23A344
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.0.0: Fri Sep 15 14:41:43 PDT 2023; root:xnu-10002.1.13~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: B5B971E36AEB2872B9B570E10D3D2BF3
Kernel UUID: BBDD4971-4AC1-34C9-B0E3-26B569022090
Boot session UUID: 2EE9B460-B266-453A-8BB4-48FEAF3D99D9
iBoot version: iBoot-10151.1.1
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
Paniclog version: 14
KernelCache slide: 0x00000000248fc000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe002b900000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000024904000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe002b908000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x0000000025e18000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe002ce1c000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1cad7348f4
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x6548a2d0 0x0000b65f
  Sleep   : 0x6549207f 0x0003e559
  Wake    : 0x65492098 0x0003aee0
  Calendar: 0x6549209b 0x000c2f46

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xfffffe1000d50000 - 0xfffffe3000d50000
  . VM    : 0xfffffe1000d50000 - 0xfffffe14cda1c000
  . RO    : 0xfffffe14cda1c000 - 0xfffffe16673b4000
  . GEN0  : 0xfffffe16673b4000 - 0xfffffe1b34080000
  . GEN1  : 0xfffffe1b34080000 - 0xfffffe2000d4c000
  . GEN2  : 0xfffffe2000d4c000 - 0xfffffe24cda18000
  . GEN3  : 0xfffffe24cda18000 - 0xfffffe299a6e4000
  . DATA  : 0xfffffe299a6e4000 - 0xfffffe3000d50000
  Metadata: 0xfffffe3f7476c000 - 0xfffffe3f7c76c000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffe3f7c76c000 - 0xfffffe3f7f528000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xfffffe2999617818  0: 0x0000000000000000  0ro: 0x0000000174acf0e0 }
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 8 PVH locks held: None
CORE 9 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffe002ce2f114, LR=0xfffffe002cfd6ddc, FP=0xfffffe8e1389bdf0
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e13e3fef0
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e13d97ef0
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e13f0bef0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e13aefef0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e13aa3ef0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e12053ef0
CORE 8: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e13f8fef0
CORE 9: PC=0xfffffe002ceaff18, LR=0xfffffe002ceaff18, FP=0xfffffe8e11f1bef0
Compressor Info: 12% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 11% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xfffffe20026d26d8: 9482 pages, 55 threads: pid 2626: Lark Helper
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe2999617818, backtrace: 0xfffffe499b58f820, tid: 43386
          lr: 0xfffffe002ce75288  fp: 0xfffffe499b58f8b0
          lr: 0xfffffe002cfce074  fp: 0xfffffe499b58f8d0
          lr: 0xfffffe002cfbebcc  fp: 0xfffffe499b58f940
          lr: 0xfffffe002cfbd040  fp: 0xfffffe499b58fa30
          lr: 0xfffffe002ce23aa4  fp: 0xfffffe499b58fa40
          lr: 0xfffffe002ce74b64  fp: 0xfffffe499b58fdf0
          lr: 0xfffffe002d686808  fp: 0xfffffe499b58fe10
          lr: 0xfffffe002e6921a0  fp: 0xfffffe499b58feb0
          lr: 0xfffffe002e692f50  fp: 0xfffffe499b58ff30
          lr: 0xfffffe002e1f8b38  fp: 0xfffffe499b58ffd0
          lr: 0xfffffe002cfc0464  fp: 0xfffffe499b58ffe0
          lr: 0xfffffe002ce23b18  fp: 0xfffffe499b58fff0
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleT6000(1.0)[48F5E09B-B638-33F0-8AA8-5239205F4D35]@0xfffffe002e68cf30->0xfffffe002e69d9d3
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[46E2D12C-E153-3DD2-999C-FFF05EC8A75E]@0xfffffe002d827940->0xfffffe002d87a227
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler(1)[69F67A54-48C8-39A4-ADF4-8905CB6B2534]@0xfffffe002df8a7f0->0xfffffe002df8b703
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[C0D16F16-0C72-35A5-AF79-0EABFDB877A1]@0xfffffe002e574490->0xfffffe002e598e53
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[33EBDCB5-9A17-329E-8C87-F4ED89130494]@0xfffffe002f5ca120->0xfffffe002f5cd1b3
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[6CB8A2DA-72EC-39A4-A40A-E5363D871F51]@0xfffffe002f958280->0xfffffe002fa09f47
         com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptControllerV2(1.0d1)[A1A4C713-2CF8-3485-8348-49F483D98B7B]@0xfffffe002e1f7070->0xfffffe002e1f98df
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[46E2D12C-E153-3DD2-999C-FFF05EC8A75E]@0xfffffe002d827940->0xfffffe002d87a227

last started kext at 335934882: com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0 (addr 0xfffffe002c2e4b10, size 5912)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 7400.26
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.filesystems.nfs   1
com.apple.filesystems.lifs  1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  2235.0.13
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  650.0.2
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L84Audio  700.46
com.apple.driver.AppleSN012776Amp   700.46
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   300.7
com.apple.driver.AppleProResHW  325.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSerialShim    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCDP29XXUpdateSupport 1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   732
com.apple.AGXG13X   275.6
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI 1
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    6.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  3.4.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispT600X-DCP   140.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  703.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleEventLogHandler   1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptControllerV2 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8110DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T600x   300.15
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000 1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   272.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   404
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kec.AppleEncryptedArchive 1
com.apple.driver.driverkit.serial   6.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1200.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 7400.26
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   7400.2
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    7400.42
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  7400.42
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSyntheticGameController   11.0.24
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOHIDPowerSource   1
com.apple.driver.AppleCallbackPowerSource   1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUVDMDriver    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   7400.34
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  7400.34
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    7400.34
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   1200.91
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   700.46
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  300.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 700.46
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    300.11
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13XRTBuddy    275.6
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  275.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 93
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer  1
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.81
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.3
com.apple.iokit.IOPortFamily    1.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT600xPCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.13.0
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL    1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T600x    800.11
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 300.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    8.24.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    1200.91
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    597
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    556
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  240
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   492
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   492
com.apple.driver.AppleRSMChannel    1
com.apple.iokit.IORSMFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleLockdownMode  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUVDM  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleANELoadBalancer   7.23.3
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   7.23.0
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   352.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIISController 300.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAudioClockLibs    300.1
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  71.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  5.0.0
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.Compression   1.0
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    14.0
```

Comment: CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the **full backtrace** for details.

Comment: @Ruskes Thanks for helping! Where can I see the full backtrace? I thought what I've included was the full backtrace...

Comment: In the console half way down

Comment: Also use this for hardware check https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Comment: There isn't a 2021 M1 Mac Pro. Do you mean a MacBook Pro? Have you done the usual tests like running in Safe Boot mode, or in a brand new user account?